code coverage showing less coverage with lambda methods
I am using testng and mockito for integration tests and unit test respectively.
I rarely using java8 lambda functions in the project. Still the code coverage showing too many lambda methods with 0% coverage
Example:

the formatFilter method is 100% covered still coverage showing lambda$formatFilter$1(String) with 0% coverage where formatFilter method never called using lambda.
How can I either cover those methods or remove it from coverage
